# The best way to check the linearity assumption in ANOVA (except using scatter plots)

Tags: linearity

I was wondering that ANOVA is based on linearity assumption. If Yes, how can I check the linearity between observations. I know using plot would be useful but it is difficult to find the degree of polynomial trend. Is there another way to check the linearity assumption.

Comment: An ANOVA looks at the relationship between a categorical predictor (or multiple of those perhaps with interaction terms) and a continuous outcome. There is a normality assumption, but I don't see a linearity assumption. Are you talking about some very specific variant of ANOVA? If yes please specify.

Comment: @user7019377, thanks for the reply. Since ANOVA and linear regression are the same, I though so ANOVA is based on linearity too.

Comment: They are the same when you only have categorical inputs.

Comment: @user7019377, yes, In my model, I have one continuous dependent and one categorical independent, So now my question is regarding checking the linearity assumption.

Comment: How can there be linearity with regard to a categorical variable? If there can be, your categorical variable is really a disguised interval variable.

Comment: @Ben and there is no assumption that there cannot be interaction terms between categoricals or that there cannot be a regression on a square of a continuous predictor. The regression is linear in its parameters, not the variables.

Comment: @Ben and you will discover such problems in the residuals since the formal assumptions are expressed in terms of the residuals not the variables. (The residuals would keep containing any systematic effect that your model doesn't allow to capture) The assumptions translate into things you need to do with the variables, but they stem from the residuals.

Comment: "there is no formal linearity assumption" means no formal linearity assumption for the variables (which the OP seemed to misunderstand there is, which would best be cured by thinking about the residuals instead). I added to my answer that there is a formal linearity restriction on parameters.  "how can than be nonlinearity with regard to a categorical variable." meant nonlinearity with regard to one single categorical. Compared to one single categorical you can only speak of (non)linearity if you have many equidistant ordinals and that's a veiled interval variable, not a real categorical.

Answer (score 3):

There is no formal linearity assumption regarding variables in a linear regression and there can also be non-linear interaction terms between different categorical variables in an ANOVA. For ANOVAs as well as regressions, there are assumptions of homoskedasticity and normality of residuals (and some others).

Those assumptions are equivalent to the response variable being linearly related to a continuous predictor in a regression. If there was a non-linear relationship that your model doesn't capture, the residuals would not be homoskedastic. They would be larger at those areas where the real trend diverges from your line.

You could still add a higher order term, perhaps the square of the variable, to your regression's predictors and see if that solves your homoskedasticity problem. For example

$$ Y = \beta X^2 + \epsilon$$

is a perfectly acceptable linear regression. The linearity lies at the $\beta$ parameter, not the variable $X$. As long as $\epsilon$ is normal and homoskedastic the assumptions of the regression are met. An example of what you cannot do would be

$$Y = X^{\text{sin}(\beta)} + \epsilon$$

since it is not linear in $\beta$ nor easy to render linear (as you sometimes can by taking the log of all terms)

In an ANOVA with only categorical predictors, you have the assumptions that the residuals (after subtracting a constant value per category) are normal within each category and have the same variance for the different categories.